# How to validate a mongoid field based on another mongoid field?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

I made the switch to nosql and am playing with Mongoid with Sinatra. I'm still new to this, and I"m stumped on this problem.

```
class Item
    field :name, type: String
    field :category, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId    # holds _id of the category object
    field :cover_type, type: String

    validates_presence_of :category
    validates_inclusion_of :cover_type, in:["Hardcover", "Softcover"]
end

class Category
    field :name

    validates_inclusion_of :name, in:["Books", "Movies", "Ebooks"]
end
```

Imagine a store that sells Books, Movies, and Ebooks and each item sold belongs to one of the three categories. If an Item is listed under the category "Books", then the Item is required to have a field called `cover_type`. Furthermore, `cover_type` can only be either "Hardcover" or "Softcover".

When saving an Item, how do I piece together the validate in the Item class for when the Item is in the Book category and therefore requires the presence of the field `cover_type`, which is also validated as being "Hardcover" or "Softcover"?

If the Item isn't a Book, then `cover_type` can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid models inherit ActiveModel validations. You can just write a [custom validator method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
class Item
  validates :cover_type_must_be_valid, if: :book?

  def book?
    Category.find(category).name == 'Books'
  end

  def cover_type_must_be_valid
    errors.add(:cover_type, 'must be Hardcover or Softcover') unless %w{Hardcover Softcover}.include? cover_type
  end
end
```

The `book?` method is unpleasant; why not use `belongs_to :category` on `Item` and `has_many :items` on `Category`?

**EDIT**: here’s what `book?` could look like if you used the `has_many` and `belongs_to`:

```
def book?
  category.name == 'Books'
end
```

Not that different, but you’ll surely be accessing `item.category` all over your application, I can’t see why you wouldn’t want to make it easier.

Comment: Can you explain why the `books?` is unpleasant? And If instead I use the `has_many :items` on `Category` and `belongs_to :category`, how would I enforce that the `cover_type` in `Item` be only Softcover and Hardcover?

Comment: It’s unpleasant because it’s having to look up a `Category` by ID, when Mongoid/ActiveModel gives you `belongs_to` for that exact reason. I’ve updated the answer with what could happen if you used those convenience methods.